# Is data-uri a solution to embed private videos?

Tags: php, laravel, html5-video, private, data-uri

I'm creating a website in laravel 4 in which authenticated users can watch only their private videos. This means Pete can watch Pete's videos but not Paulie's.

Since the videos are private to each user, they can't possibly be in the public folder. But then, what can I put in the src attribute? Hoho! Just slap in the data and call it a day! The controller checks if the user can see the video and then serves it like [this](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri):

```
<video controls> 
    <source type="video/webm" src="<?php echo getEncodedVideoString('webm', 'parrots-small.webm'); ?>"> 
    <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo getEncodedVideoString('mp4', 'parrots-small.mp4');?>">
</video>
```

And just like that, no link is ever required and Pete won't peek!

But for some unexplainable reason, I have this feeling that behind my back Torvalds' hand is raising above my neck to give me a majestic slap.

Is there a proper way to do this? Will angry programmers stalk me home?

Answer (score 1):

Embedding a video as a data URL in an HTML page is pretty silly, especially since videos are generally large files and the Base64 encoding of a data URL adds a size overhead of roughly 33%.

Use a normal URL to request the video from the server, and configure the server to check whether the requesting user is allowed to access the requested video, and return a 403 Forbidden response if not.

Comment: How do I do this? You mean I should leave it in public and somehow control access with a mixture of .htaccess and php? Could you paste an example? Will this let me embed a <video>? I have no trouble if I just want to let the user download it.

Comment: You could maybe do it with `.htaccess`, or you could write a PHP page that takes a video ID as a query parameter and does an access check before outputting the video file's contents. (The video file itself shouldn't be directly accessible via a URL, only the PHP page that acts as a front-end to it.)

Comment: Yeah, I tried warped my head around both scenarios. The issue appears when I try to embed a video because I don't know what to put in the src tag.

Comment: You put a URL that will download the video via the PHP script that controls access:  something like `http://yourserver/video.php?videoID=12345`

Comment: Yeah, but I want to embed the video to watch online, not download it.

Comment: Watching a video works by downloading it in order to play it.  Instead of "a URL that will download the video", should I say "a URL that will cause the server to send the video file's contents if the user is authorized"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60201/discussion-between-brunch875-and-wyzard).